# KEYCLOAK Why do I get the authorization_request_not_found error after the login screen has been idle SOME TIME?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

When I log out of the app and try to log back in after a few minutes, I can do it successfully. However, after a long time of inactivity of the login screen, when trying to log in, I get the error authorization_request_not_found.[link address here is http://localhost:9090/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-confidential-user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR1t3.jpg)

Clicking the link from the screenshot opens the wrong URL: http://localhost:9090, while the URL of the application is http://localhost:9090/list. Then I have to manually enter the correct address of the application in the bar and only then do I get access as a logged in user.

What is this error due to? I expect the login screen to work properly indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question: although I don't know why the "authorization_request_not_found" error occurred after 30 minutes, I know how to prevent it. Not with any Keycloak settings, only in application.yml the appropriate value of server.servlet.session.timeout should be set. I had this value empty.